# Interference : the cause of current

Tags: waves, electricity, interference

The wave nature of electrons was proved in the Davisson and Germer experiment since the Galvanometer they used showed a sudden peak in the value of current.

Now I have some doubts regarding this.

**1** : Does the amperemeter or galvanometer which we use in our general circuits also measure the value of the current obtained by the **constructive interference of the electrons** accelerating in the wire?

**2** : Also, isn't the equation

$I = \frac {Q}{T}$

wrong then, since we can't calculate the exact numbers of electrons because the result which we get is due to the interference of flowing electrons?

Help me clearing these doubts. I know they are more than one, but I think all are interlinked.

Comment: If something is not clear then leave a comment .

Comment: Also I didn't know what to add in the tags . So help me with them also.

Answer (score 0):

> So does the ammeter or galvanometer which we use in our general circuits also measure the value of the current obtained by the constructive interference of the electrons accelerating in the wire ?

Not in any practical way. Perhaps in theory, but on a macroscopic level those microscopic interferences are incoherent.

There are two key features of the Davisson and Germer experiment that are missing in ordinary circuits. First, ordinary circuits don’t feature very large single crystals through which all the current passes. Second, ordinary circuits don’t have such a narrow range of electron energies right in the wavelength of the crystal spacing.

The first is the electronic equivalent of making a diffraction gratings, and the second is the electronic equivalent of illuminating the grating with monochromatic light. Without these two effects the electrons are incoherent and constructive interference is absent.

With your first question answered in the negative, the other questions go away. However, I did want to point out that question 3 is about the definition of current and definitions cannot be wrong.